# Rather strange MYSQL UTF-8 encoding error

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a table called 'users'

There is a user named "janis"

Well, the problem is as follows - when I try to SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'janis' Everything goes as expected. But, when I put in jānis (that's a UTF-8 character of a) it still returns the same user.

No other UTF-8 character is showing this behaviour. For example, I can put in janiš or janīs and there won't be any results found.

collation is of course UTF-8, headers are sending utf-8 as charset and mysqli_set_charset is at utf-8 too.

Any ideas?

```
function getUser($username){
    $result = $this->fetchOne("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    return $result;
}

$handler->getUser("janis");
```

Comment: you are sending query from php? write down the full code

Comment: @Riad see edited topic

Comment: Is this really the code you are using? Because if it is, it's one giant SQL injection vulnerability right here.

Comment: @KarolS of course not, I left only the main parts.